# How to show javascript variable value inside response html code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I want user to comment without reloading their page. For that i have applied ajax through jquery. When the response comes i have append the html code into the blade.

```
 success: function(res)
            {
                
                var first_name = res.first_name;
                var last_name = res.last_name;
                var profilepic = res.profilepic;
                var created_at = res.created_at;
                $('.profile_comment').prepend(
                        '<div class="others_comment d-flex mb-15">'+
                            '<div class="users-img">'+
                                '<img @if(!empty('+profilepic+')) src="{{URL::asset("uploads/memberprofile/" . '+profilepic+')}}" @else src="{{URL::asset("member/assets/images/user.png")}}" @endif alt="user" class="img-fluid">'+
                            '</div>'+
                            '<div class="user_side">'+
                                '<div class="d-flex">'+
                                    '<h6 class="name">{{ucfirst('+first_name+')}} {{ucfirst('+last_name+')}}</h6>'+
                                    '@php $date= date("F d,Y", strtotime('+created_at+'));  @endphp'+
                                    '<p class="ml-auto font-xs">{{$date}}</p>'+
                                '</div>'+
                                '<p class="comment">{{ucfirst('+comment+')}}</p>'+
                                '<div  class="footer_comment d-flex">'+
                                    '<button class="btn-none ml-auto"> <img src="{{URL::asset("member/assets/images/option.svg")}}" alt="option" class="img-fluid"> </button>'+
                                '</div>'+
                            '</div>'+
                        '</div>'
                );
```

This is the code i have tried so far. But it doesn't show the value inside the variable.

Comment: can you show html code also,
if you want to get answer quickly or more perfect just give more information pls

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic problem when working with Blade and JavaScript. The way Blade works is it will look at your template then compile it into a proper `.php` file that the browser can interpret.

What is happening here, is that before any script is executed blade will run all its directives. For example, the line below:

```
'<img @if(!empty('+profilepic+')) src="{{URL::asset("uploads/memberprofile/" . '+profilepic+')}}" @else src="{{URL::asset("member/assets/images/user.png")}}" @endif alt="user" class="img-fluid">'
```

Will transform into something similar to

```
'<img src="localhost/storage/uploads/memberprofile/+profilepic+" alt="user" class="img-fluid">'
```

before any scripts are executed (so before the ajax call). I have encountered this problem before and depending on how complicated the use case was I solved it in 2 ways, it's up to you which one to go for:

1. Use JS for everything in your ajax callback and make use of the variables you receive from response: `first_name`, `last_name`, etc. This can get quite tedious if you have complicated logic or you use a lot of PHP in front end.
2. Generate the HTML elements on the server side and send back the whole html as a string.

```
// server side
return response()->json(['element' => $elementString]);

// client side
$('.profile_comment').prepend(res.element);
```